# Inception model for lung cancer detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a lung cancer detection system using Kaggle lung cancer data set. The main idea is to use Very deep neural network such as using Inception model. I was thinking of using Inception model but seemed it is not an easy task.

Inception and other networks trained on ImageNet expect 2D RGB images as inputs.

Therefore I need to adjust my data accordingly.

Here is the shape of my current data

```
much_data = np.load('../../CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET/muchdata-50-50-20.npy')
print ('Image 0',much_data[0][0].shape)
print ('Image 1',much_data[1][0].shape)
print ('Image 2',much_data[2][0].shape)
```

And here is the output.

```
Image 0 (128, 512, 512)
Image 1 (133, 512, 512)
Image 2 (110, 512, 512)
```

For an example,
Image 0 (128, 512, 512)

128 is the number of slices of lung for a patient and 512,512 is the number of pixels of each slice. So this is a 3D array.

But I found a code which generates a Inception model for MNIST data set and its input images shape was like only (60000, 28, 28) used for 28*28 pixeled data for 60000 images.

Can anyone suggest me how I can use my existing data to use for the inception model.
Do I need to convert them to a 2D array?

Or any other approach that I need to follow?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to use a pretrained network, trained on very very different images (different channels alone sounds very problematic)?

Comment: Hi Sasha... Can't I train Inception model from the scratch?

Comment: Sure you can. But better have millions of samples, many GPUs and you also should modify this network if it's build for RGB, while your data is not.

Comment: I understand... with the limited amount of data seems this is impossible.